# Adding GA Event code to Joomla {tab}

Tags: joomla, tabs, google-analytics

I am trying to add a Google Analytics event to track if a tab has been clicked on in a page. I am using Joomla 2.5.7 and in the article is has this markup for the tabs extension:

```
<p>{tab Rates}</p>
```

This is the tab at the top of the page. I want to add the following universal analytics tracking event code:

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'tab active', 'click', 'rates');"
```

to track when someone looks at this tab.

Currently I have only used this `onclick` event on an anchor, but as using Joomla this isn't working and is just showing up on the page.

Please advise the best place to get this information and how to activate it. Thanks all.

Comment: Off topic: Your Joomla installation is sorely out of date and insecure. It's a one-click update to 2.5.27. Then, the 2.5.x strand reaches end of life in 3 weeks. Normally a J!3.x upgrade is pretty painless, too.

Comment: What language is that first block? Joomla is written in PHP, and near as I can tell that isn't PHP.

Comment: @isherwood What do you mean by the first block and where would i look to find it for you?

Comment: This is the user guide for the tabs... hope this help http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/tabs/userguide

Comment: Oh, I get it. What you're calling the "back end" isn't actually back-end (server-side) code. It's markup in the article. You'll probably want to look into template overrides and build your GA code into the template for the tabs extension. It may be difficult to do what you want in the content itself.

Comment: Someone else asked about this very thing on the NoNumber forum. You might want to resurrect that discussion and ask specifically about template overrides. https://www.nonumber.nl/forum/TabsPRO/33945-Tabs-with-Google-Analytics